# Ruby on rails : launch server with code reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using a server for testing my api. I use this command to launch the server :

```
rails s -p 3001 -e test -P 42342
```

I change the port to 3001, to not have a conflict with my dev server (on port 3000).
The thing is that when I change code, the server don't reload the code, I have to kill the server and relaunch.

Is there a parameters that I miss to launch my rails command ?

Comment: Why are you running the `test` environment? I guess this is the cause, just remove the `-e test` flag and run in development mode, code will be autoreloaded.

Answer (score 2):

`test` is only designed for automated testing, with Rails running for a single test run. Since code should not be changing during a test case, it doesnt have many of the development mode features and is more like production in that regard. Its also intended to reset your database when running tests, which also doesnt seem to be your intention.

If you want (most) classes to auto-reload, always use the `development` environment.

If for some reason you need a different environment (more than just port, but different configs), you can look at creating a new environment, copying the configs for `development` (add new entries to `config/environments/`, `config/database.yml`, `config/secrets.yml`, and use as a group in the `Gemfile`.).